# Using flatfileitemreader read 10 lines as one record

Tags: spring-batch

Flatfileitemreader read one line as one record but i want to read 10 lines as one record. is there any way to do it.

```
public FlatFileItemReader<List<SMSData>> flatFileItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<List<SMSData>> flatFileItemReader = 
                new FlatFileItemReader<List<SMSData>>();
        
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\Users\\mdtouhid.it\\Downloads\\Flat-File-Item-Reader-In-Action\\InputFiles\\finalsms4appr1.csv")));
                        
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        flatFileItemReader.setMaxItemCount(10);
        
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        System.out.println("Inside Item flat file reader" + flatFileItemReader);
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }
```

in this line mapper is want to print 10 lines in the line variable

```
@Bean
    LineMapper<List<SMSData>> lineMapper() {
        return new LineMapper<List<SMSData>>() {
            
            @Override
            public List<SMSData> mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 System.out.println("Inside line  print: " + line);

                 List<SMSData> data = new ArrayList<SMSData>();
                 data.add(SMSData.of(line));
                
                 return data;
                
            }
            
            
            
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample of how to this here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#multiline

You need a custom reader, similar to this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java#L44.